# How passing installationpath as parameter to a MSI file made with WIX

Tags: c#, wpf, wix

I have produced a MSI file with Windows Installer XML and the selected dialog set is "WixUI_Advanced".
Then i want to start that MSI from a WPF-Window by clicking a Button and passing the installation path as parameter to the MSI.
So i'm using the following code to start the MSI:

```
Process proc = new Process();
   proc.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec";
   string filePath = "C:\\experimente\\WpfTestApplication\\TestSetup\\bin\\Debug\\TestSetup.msi";
   proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/i " + filePath + " INSTALLATIONPATH=C:\\workspace";
   proc.Start();
```

In the Product.wxs of the WIX-Project i defined the property INSTALLATIONPATH:

C:\Installation

And later i try to set the given parameter in the Id where normally stands "ProgramFilesFolder":

```
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR"
               Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLATIONPATH">
            <Directory Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER"
                       Name="TestApplication">
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
```

When i start my WPF-App and push the Button, the MSI starts, but the installationpath is still the programfilesfolder.
Can anybody tell me please, what i've made wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

That's quiet simple - if You know it!

You need - next to Your MSI project and Your application - a bootstrapper project called p.e. "BootstrapperSetup".
In the Bundle.wxs You write:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
    <Bundle Name="ProsoftSetupForTest" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="prosoft GmbH" UpgradeCode="b6f80b17-7a36-425c-a1e5-9c9e7e500da2">
        <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />

        <Variable Name="INSTALLFOLDER"
                  bal:Overridable="yes"
                  Type="string"
                  Value="[ProgramFilesFolder]"/>

        <Chain>
            <MsiPackage Vital="yes"
                        DisplayName="<The setup identifier for the program registry>"
                        Id="MsiId"
                        SourceFile="<The path of Your MSI">
                <MsiProperty Name="TARGETDIR"
                             Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]\MyFolder" />
            </MsiPackage>
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

And in the Product.wxs of Your MSI You have a TARGETDIR entry like the following:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR"
    Name="SourceDir">
</Directory>
```

Then You rebuild Your solution, go in the Windows Explorer to the Debug folder of Your bootstrapper project, start a DOS-window and set a command like this:

```
BootstrapperSetup.exe INSTALLFOLDER=C:\TestInstallation
```

That's all!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
    <Variable Name="INSTALLFOLDER"
                     bal:Overridable="yes"
                     Type="string"
                     Value="[InstallFolder]"/>

    <Chain>
       <MsiPackage Id="Id"
            SourceFile="MSI path"
            DisplayName="Title"
            Vital="yes"
            Visible="no">
             <Payload SourceFile="msi Path" />
        <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLFOLDER" Value="[InstallFolder]" />
        </MsiPackage>
    </Chain>
</Bundle>
```

Comment: You should add explanation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).